# a header unexpectedly shows up in all view controllers in iOS 10 and lower

Tags: swift, layout, constraints

all my view controllers and constraints are fine in iOS 11 and above but in iOS 10 and below a space created in all pages like the pictures below :

[image]

[image]

I tried even a simple web view in a viewcontroller with four constraints to safe area but I've got the same result.(good view in iOS 11 and above and a space to top in iOS 10 and below. and another strange thing is that some of my apps now have this problem and some don't :| . what should I do?

Comment: [How to take a screenshot on your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200289)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Note: Use (tableView, collectionView) instead of scrollview if you are using one.