# UIKit - Swift - Allow tableHeaderView to scroll up, but not down

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I have a UIViewController with a navigation bar and a tab bar. Other than that, the whole screen is made up of a UITableView.

I have a large tableHeaderView that has the same background color as the navbar.

When I drag the content up (scrolling down) everything looks fine.

But if I drag it up, there is an ugly disconnection between the navigation bar and the header view.

Is there any way I could anchor it to the top when dragging down, while allowing it to scroll when dragging up?

[image]

Comment: Make the background color of the viewCotroller the same as the header. Easiest solution.

Comment: can u please attach a screenshot for that ugly disconnection to have an idea about what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla, that would give me a similar problem on the bottom, under the prototype cells.

Comment: @AyoubNouri, I made a screen recording, but I need to figure out a way to get it onto the question.

Comment: Ok, I added a screenshot. Don't mind the bad constraints and blurry image.

Comment: @CalebH. Is it the similar problem ? [Can you try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53635727/a-header-unexpectedly-shows-up-in-all-view-controllers-in-ios-10-and-lower/53635977#53635977)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating a view and placing it behind the `tableView`, as the table view scrolls, the height of the view is updated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    lazy var tableView : UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        return tableView
    }()

    let backView : UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()

    var backViewHeight : NSLayoutConstraint?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "ViewController"

        self.view.addSubview(backView)
        backView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        backView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        backView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        backViewHeight = backView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        backViewHeight?.isActive = true

        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.register(Cell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.register(Header.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "header")
        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setValue(true, forKey: "hidesShadow")

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }


    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
            backViewHeight?.constant = -scrollView.contentOffset.y
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "header")
        header?.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
        let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: 100))
        headerLabel.textAlignment = .center
        headerLabel.text = "Header"
        header?.addSubview(headerLabel)
        return header
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        return view
    }

}

class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    let label : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "One Label"
        return label
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        self.backgroundColor = .white
        self.addSubview(label)
        label.frame = self.frame
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class Header : UITableViewHeaderFooterView {


    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

If you copy paste this code in an empty project you can have a look at the behavior. Don't forget to embed the `ViewController` in a `NavigationController`. Hope it helps

Comment: This could work. I'll try it once I have time. Why does everything in Swift/UIKit feel so hacky to me? I'm coming from React Native and HTML/CSS/JS, so this is very confusing to me.

Comment: mmm. I don't think this is too hacky. The thing is that there are certain things that you cannot avoid in iOS. For example the pull down of a scrollView needs to be there. Otherwise you wouldn't get the feeling you are used to in pull to refresh. Some things need a workaround and there is not much you can do about it. In CSS for example you will probably just fix the header and hide it with scroll, but there is no overflow on the way up, here you need the overflow of the scrollView.

Comment: Yea, this one isn't too bad, but my point is that what the user thinks they are seeing is not what they are actually seeing in certain cases. I definitely forgot about pull to refresh, and I realize that would be a great place to put that...

Comment: could you please explain what is the role of "backView" in your solution

Comment: @AbidNawaz. Caleb’s problem is that when he scrolls the tableView down there is a gap between the header and the navigation bar. The gap has a different color and he just doesn’t like it. The backView is placed behind the tableView and below the navigationBar. As the user scrolls down, this view fills the gap making everything the same color.

Answer (score -1):

1) If an unwanted white space on the top of tableview is permanent and the constraints are correct this is the solution. 
the scroll view insets adjusted automatically if you disable it should remove it

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

2) if u just have it when u pull down and it goes back to its normal state. It means is that the tableview bouncing is enabled and that is normal behaviour according to iOS documentation:

If the value of this property is true, the scroll view bounces when it encounters a boundary of the content. Bouncing visually indicates that scrolling has reached an edge of the content. If the value is false, scrolling stops immediately at the content boundary without bouncing. The default value is true.

you can uncheck the bouncing from the tableview in your storyboard or xib file. Or u can use this snippet:

```
tableView.bounces = false
tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
```

**Note:** that is not recommended to disable the scroll bouncing since it would make things feel very unnatural for iOS.
and also if you want to use pull to refresh it will not work.

So finally if u choose to not disable it you will have to change the background color of the parent of your tableview and it will solve it.

I hope that makes sense!

Comment: I didn't vote it down, but it doesn't address the problem. The extra space is only there when I pull it down.

Comment: Yea, I decided just to use pull to refresh there, but otherwise I like the other answer a bit better, because it keeps the natural feel and doesn't change the background color.